# Consuming Azure REST API in C# application shows no response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, rest, azure-rest-api

When I try a azure rest api url on azure docs post man, I am able to get a json which has all the resource groups.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/list#code-try-0[a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/list#code-try-0)

[image]

But I am trying it from a ASP.NET MVC Core C# application, I am receiving an empty array.

```
    public async Task<ResourceGroupModel> GetResourceGroupStatus()
    {
        ResourceGroupModel resourceGroupModel = null;
        try         
        { 
            string requestUrlString = iconfiguration.GetValue<string>("HealthSettings:AzureGetResourcesBySubscriptionURL");
            string azureSubscription = iconfiguration.GetValue<string>("HealthSettings:AzureSubscription");
            string clientId = iconfiguration.GetValue<string>("HealthSettings:ClientId");
            string tenantId = iconfiguration.GetValue<string>("HealthSettings:TenantId");
            string clientSecret = iconfiguration.GetValue<string>("HealthSettings:ClientSecret");
            Uri requestUrl = new Uri(requestUrlString.Replace("{subscriptionId}", azureSubscription));

            string token = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);

            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                resourceGroupModel = ResourceGroupModel.FromJson(data.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return resourceGroupModel;
    }
```

Could you please help me to get rid of strange behavior of Azure REST API. Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you also show the ResourceGroupModel class (with FromJson method also)?

Comment: The element "data" itself shows "value : []"

Comment: Are you using a service principal in order to call this API?

Comment: Yes, I am using service principle to call the Azure REST API.

Comment: @joeryCai I have added myself as contributor in IAM of the subscruption, but no luck, I am still receiving an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the existing clientsecret and creating new one for service principle solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your service principal does not have access to the resource group.

1. Log into Azure Portal and select the Resource Group
2. Select Access control (IAM) from the Blade
3. On Check access tab, Add a role assignment
4. Give your service principal a role (Owner/Contributor/Reader)
5. Assign access to: Azure AD user, group, or service principal
6. Type your Service Principal name, search and select it then Save.
7. Wait a couple of minutes and try again calling your API.

Comment: Thanks for providing steps, but it didn't helped me :(

Answer (score 0):

As Ciubotariu said, your service principal does not have access to the resource group. However, if you only add your service principal to the resource group, you could only get the specify resource group. So, **add your service principal to your Subscription**. Here are the steps:

1.Go to your subscription, click Access Control> Add(Add role assignment)
[image]

2.Add your service principal and assign a role to it like Contributor.
[image]

3.Then you will get all the resource groups for a subscription.
[image]

Update:

4.Here is the full code I used:

```
var appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://management.azure.com/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl +
                    @"subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-05-01";
    var response = client.GetAsync(requestURl).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: I have added myself as contributor in IAM of the subscruption, but no luck, I am still receiving an empty array.

Comment: Do you add the service principal you registered in subscription? I recreate a new sp and it works well after several minutes.